# How Django and JavaScript work together for running Python script?

Tags: javascript, django

I am wondering how to accomplish the below with Django:

- Consider a function in JavaScript:

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
    var rand_val = Math.random();
    // here some code sends this rand_val to a Python script in Django app
    // as seen below, script is run and generates result
    alert('This is the result ' + result);  
})
```

- The script in the Django app:

```py
def my_func(rand_val):
    # result = (some operations with rand_val)
    return result
```

The Python script will be run in Django virtual environment.

With a button click, run a Python script and show the result on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the data with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) get,

```
var url = "url_to_my_func_view/" + rand_val
$.get( url, function( data ) {
   alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

You will need to return your result as bytes or JSON using HttpResponse or JsonResponse.

Edit:

If you need to send back user input (as the OP explained in the comments), then you are better off with GET or POST params. In JS you would do like so,

```
var url = 'url_to_my_func_view/'
$.get( url, {'user_val': rand_val}, function( data ) {
   alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Then in your view you would catch those params like so,

```
def my_func(request):
   user_val = request.GET['user_val']
   return user_val
```

Notice that your function receives a request!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works without arguments. But not sure how to deal with arguments. How _var url = "url_to_my_func_view/" + rand_val_ should be evaluated in Django? Suppose I am sending multiple arguments.

Comment: This is the url dispatcher job. Read here to learn how to write your urls.py  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/.

Comment: If you are sending multiple vars such as a form input by a user, then its a different story. You will need to send those variables as GET or POST parameters, then catch them back at your view.

Comment: I am not using a form. The user makes visual selections on the page, then those selections are converted to a list. I want to send this list along with some others.

Comment: Then you are better off with GET or POST params. I edited the question and added and example to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A small edit: comma after {'user_val': rand_val}

Answer (score 0):

To perform form submission through Ajax, need to use some specific code snippets. I am adding the details source code so, you might find these helpful!

The code in JavaScript file:

```
//The functions below will create a header with csrftoken for Ajax based submission in Django application

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
// Ajax setup end

$('#button').click(function(e){
    var rand_val = Math.random();

    $.post('/my_func/', { rand_val: rand_val }, function(data){
        return false;
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In views.py:

```
def my_func(request):
    response = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rand_val = request.POST.get('rand_val')
        # result = (some operations with rand_val)

        return result
```

In urls.py: Django v2.x

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
import APP_NAME.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('my_func/', APP_NAME.views.my_func),
]
```

Expecting the code will work for you!